# Is a Ring with $|R|=k$ an Integral domain if k is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the Ring of integers modulo $n$,
$\mathbb{Z}  /  n \mathbb{Z}$.
I know that $\mathbb{Z}  /  n \mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain iff n is a prime number.

Assumption:
Let $R$ be a Ring with finite Elements, |R|=k
Then R is an integral domain iff k is a prime number.

I have been trying to prove this, but I am new to algebra and do struggle a little bit.
My Idea: Since there is only a finite amount of Elements in $R=${$r_0,...,r_k$}, I can define an Isomorphism:
$\phi : \mathbb{Z}  /  n \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ as follows:
$\phi(\overline{i})=r_i$ for i=0,...,k

Thus, the same prove as in $\mathbb{Z}  /  n \mathbb{Z} $ holds in $R$. (If I do the prove for $\mathbb{Z}  /  n \mathbb{Z}$, I could to the same thing in $R$ with $\phi(\overline{i})$)

Is my assumption correct?

Is my prove correct?

Comment: Your proof is incorrect, you must show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism which it isn't if I don't know how the $r_i$ interact with one another. I think one way you might want to think about this is to consider the element $1\in R$ and think about the ring that $1$ generates.

Comment: You can take the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and give it the trivial multiplication:  $xy=0$ for all $x, y$.  This is a ring without identity and therefore not an integral domain.  If you want an example where the ring has an identity but is still not an integral domain you have to work a little bit more.

Comment: There are integral domains of size $p^m$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $m.$

Comment: How do you know $\phi$ is an isomorphism? As defined, it is just a bijective function, and it doesn't even necessarily send $0$ in one ring to $0$ in the other, much less the very many other restrictions required for a isomorphism. Most functions are not homomorphisms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I forgot to check if $\phi$ is a isomorphism. Does this mean that, for example there is no integral domains with just 10 Elements, because 10 can't be written as $p^m$?

Comment: Right. You can show for a finite ring that there is a homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to R,$ and the image is isomorphic $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for some prime $p$ if $R$ is an integral domain. Then you can use that $R$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ to show that $|R|=p^m$ for some $m.$ So there are no integral domains of size $10.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much